# iOS: What is the difference between "background fetch" and "background refresh"

Tags: ios, background, refresh, fetch

I develop iOS app for my customer.
My customer asks me to add "Background Refresh" feature to the app.
I know that there is a screen in iOS Settings app that is called "Background App Refresh".
But the underlying feature itself known as "Background Fetch".

I am stuck explaining the customer that the feature is "Fetch", and not "Refresh".

So the question is: how "Background Refresh" relates to "Background Fetch" iOS SDK feature?
Are they the same just called differently.
Or "Background refresh" feature is more than "Background Fetch" itself?

If these two terms call for the same feature, so why Apple created 2 terms for the same feature instead the only one?

Just want to know reasons of why Apple used 2 similar (but still different) terms to call a feature. Searching for some logic basement for this.

Comment: @robdashnash I'm sorry, but you didn't understand. "Background Fetch" is how the feature called in iOS SDK. I'm searching for the answer why this technical feature called differently in Settings and in iOS SDK.